# Select specific fields from query

Tags: craft3, entry, php, yii, element

I'm trying to get tags out of the underlying craft DB and serve it as a REST endpoint - however, I'm only interested in exposing the tag id and title, so my data should look like this:

```
{id: 1, title: "hello"}, {id: 2, title: "test"}
```

I'm currently able to achieve this with the following query:

```
$tags = \craft\elements\Tag::find()->all();
```

The problem with this is that this returns all the fields the tag has. I then have to filter out the two fields I want by doing:

```
foreach($tags as $tag) {
   $out = [];
   $out['id'] = $tag['id'];
   $out['title'] = $tag['title'];
   return $out;
}
```

This is quite wasteful as I'm fetching a bunch of fields I don't need from the DB, then looping through all the tags and parsing out the two fields I need.

What I'd like to do instead is only fetch these two fields from craft in my query.

I found two possible ways of doing this - one of them uses the `select` method:

Something like

```
$tags = \craft\elements\Tag::find()->select(['id', 'title']).all();
```

The problem with the above code is that the SQL query which is executed by the above doesn't actually have fields called `id` and `title` due to aliasing and joins being carried out on multiple tables - therefore I'd have to know exactly which fields I want and in which table in the SQL schema they sit...this doesn't scale well for more complex queries.

I also found https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-arrayable#fields()-detail which seems like it could be useful but I wasn't able to get this to work at all and the documentation isn't too helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I tried eager loading before, and I couldn't figure out how to do it.

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/eager-loading-elements.html

Now I just query it using SQL. I know it's a bit hacking, but it gets the job done. The DB structure of `craft_content` table hasn't change since Craft 2 (when I started using craft), so its unlikely that future updates will break your code.

```
$command = Craft::$app->getDB()->createCommand("SELECT `ct`.`id`, `cc`.`title` FROM `craft_tags` as `ct` left join `craft_content` as `cc` on `ct`.`id` = `cc`.`elementId`");
$tags = $command->queryAll();
```

This is only a quick fix, if anyone had a better idea, just ignore this answer.